# Continue table on new page when new column is added

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm currently generating a table in Word with VB.Net, and I was wondering if it is possible to 'break' the table when a new column is created, like when you add a new row, it can break the table, and continue on a new page with table headers.

It would be useful since my program generates only columns, and Word tries to make the table fit on the page, even if there are to many columns to be rendered.

I'm generating commercial quotation based on information given by a client (configuration for machines), and currently the table has 3 columns, but the number might grow up if the client has more than 3 demands.

Answer (score 0):

Just being curious, why is it required to be done in MS-Word?

Or maybe just set the page as horizontal, generate your table row by row, but with all text in table cells set to 90 Degree rotated. Then you'll get a horzitonal splitted long-table across multi pages.

Comment: I added the reason for more clarity at the end of the question. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it will be easier in Excel or HTML tables as Word tables are a bit frustrating.

You can make each column a separate table, then in the table properties you can select `Text wrapping` `Around` so that the tables are next to each other, and in `Positioning...` you can adjust the `Left:` and `Right:` `Distance from surrounding text` to decrease the space between the tables.